# Ember convert PATCH call to PUT

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-data, httprequest

I am using ember 2.18, in this the update requests are PATCH. However, the backend is in SAILS and it does not support PATCH. Hence, I have to convert patch request to PUT.

I saw [this](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/3870) issue and people seems to have solved it there. But it does not work for me. The code is as follows:

```js
import App from './../app';
import DS from "ember-data";
import { computed } from "@ember/object";
import { camelize } from '@ember/string';

import JSONAPIAdapter from "ember-data/adapters/json-api";

export default DS.JSONAPIAdapter.extend({
  coalesceFindRequests: true,
  host: App.GPT.Configuration.restServer,
  methodForRequest: ({ requestType }) => {
    console.log('Log')
    if (requestType === "updateRecord") {
      return "PUT";
    }

    return this._super(...arguments);
  },
  pathForType(type) {
    return camelize(type) + 's';
  },
  headers: computed(function () {
    if (!App.StoreUtil.getSessionId()) {
      if (App.GPT.ApplicationController) {
        App.GPT.ApplicationController.set("hasMessages", [
          {
            message: "Session expired."
          }
        ]);
        App.GPT.ApplicationController.transitionToRoute("/");
      } else {
        window.location = "/";
      }
    }
    return {
      sid: App.StoreUtil.getSessionId()
    };
  }).volatile()


});
```

The code added to convert the request to PUT is :

```js
methodForRequest: ({ requestType }) => {
    console.log('Log')
    if (requestType === "updateRecord") {
      return "PUT";
    }

    return this._super(...arguments);
  }
```

However, the method is not called at all. The funny part is pathForType is called for every request.

Answer (score 1):

`methodForRequest` will only be available if you are using `ember-data 2.8`+ and you have the `ds-improved-ajax` flag enabled in `environment.js`

your other option is to override `updateRecord()`